# Contour around intersected (clipped) area

Tags: scoping, path-clipping

I would like to know how to draw a (visible) contour around a clipped figure in Latex. As a basic example, consider some basic Venn diagram like that:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{scope}
   \clip    (-1, 0) circle (1);
   \fill[color=gray]    (1, 0) circle (1.5);
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This should produce that following picture:

[image: Intersection]

As you can see, it only shows the intersected area of the two circles. I would also like to draw its contour (i.e. the boundary which confines the clipped area). PS I don't care about the circles' contours. I can always add them afterwards.

I experimented with **\filldraw** instead of **\fill**, but nothing changed. Do you know what should I do? Any solution, not necessarily involving **scope** environment, will also suffice.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that all the arc routines use angles instead of x,y locations, so one has to compute the starting and ending angles using `atan2`.

You can draw the border inside the scope, but it will be clipped and appear thinner (half inside, half outside).

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{scope}
     \path[clip, name path=myclip]    (-1, 0) circle (1);
     \path[fill=gray, draw=black, name path=myfill]  (1, 0) circle (1.5);
     \path[name intersections={of=myclip and myfill}];
   \end{scope}
   \path (intersection-1);% compute angles
   \pgfgetlastxy{\xa}{\ya}%
   \path (intersection-2);
   \pgfgetlastxy{\xb}{\yb}%
   \path (-1,0);% center
   \pgfgetlastxy{\xc}{\yc}%
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mystartangle}{atan2((\ya-\yc),(\xa-\xc))}%
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\myendangle}{atan2((\yb-\yc),(\xb-\xc))}%

   \draw (intersection-1) arc[start angle=\mystartangle, end angle=\myendangle, radius=1];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 3):

One manual way to solve the problem is by using two (or however many components you have) **scope** environments. Use the first one to draw the part of the contour which comes with from the clipped figure + the filling. Then switch the role of the clipper and the clipped figures and draw the remaining contours (without the filling). For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{scope} % draws the contour from the right circle
  \clip    (-1, 0) circle (1); % clipper = left circle
  \draw[black, fill=gray]    (1, 0) circle (1.5); % clipped = right circle
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope} % draws the contour from the left circle
  \clip    (1, 0) circle (1.5); % clipper = right circle
  \draw[black]    (-1, 0) circle (1); % clipped = left circle
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is the following:

[image]

Obviously, this is a sub-par programming technique, but at least it works. There is probably a well-written operation, which does the same without the redundant code.

PS If you fill also the second scoped area, this will affect the border of the first one. For this reason, I recommend to leave it unfull.